# How to load a .json file from java/ instead of resources/

Tags: java, json

First of all, I'm very aware that you have to put everything except source code files into the resources directory in Java **by design**.

Sometimes, however, especially **JSON files may act** as a **code extension**, containing structures that you want to have **close to related source code** files and keep them in focus during development, and not "hidden" in the resource directory somewhere.

[image]

That's what you'd also do in the **Web / Node environment**, where you'd import a JSON from your .js / .ts file and comingle it with the rest of your code.

**Is it somehow possible to do that in Java as well, be it by customizing the Gradle configuration, etc?**

Comment: Sure. Put the JSON files in the code folder. It won't work that way at runtime (there is no source folder at runtime), but you could add a step to your build to copy JSON to the resources folder.

Comment: But then you have to also change the path during build to access the correct directory

Comment: *But then you have to also change the path during build to access the correct directory* We just copied the JSON to the correct directory. Why do we also have to change the path?

Comment: Ah, you came to Java from Node. Really, **don't** put data files where people would expect source code. Maintainers will hate you for that. BUT you *can* do it, to your code it is no difference, since at runtime the java and resources directories get merged anyway.

Comment: @barfuin Not really, I started with Java and do web stuff here and then, but I like the approach and freedom in this regard, especially when you package by feature.